# jQuery - How to find a row in html table and replace its text with new text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get a row by a hidden field value and replace the old text with new text.

My table looks like this:

```
var $data = $('<table id="mytable"  class="table  table-striped"> </table>');
    var header = "<thead><tr><th>Property Name</th><th>Edit</th></tr></thead>";
    $data.append(header);
    $.each(response.list, function (i, row) {
        var $row = $('<tr/>');
        $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.PropertyName));
        $hidden = $(' <input type="hidden" name="hid" value= "' + row.PropertyId + '">');
        $row.append($hidden);


        $editButton = $("<button class='editbtn' id='mybtn'>Edit</button>");

        $row.append($editButton);
        $deleteButton = $("<button class='deletebtn' id='delbtn'>Delete</button>");

        $row.append($deleteButton);
        $data.append($row);
```

I tried to find the row by Hidden field value and replace the old text with new text with this code but it didn't work:

```
$('#mytable tr').find('td').eq(0).find(HiddelFieldValue).find('td').eq(1).html('New Text');
```

Comment: You only have one `<td>`, and you append all the rest outside of `<td>`. Still, you'll probably be able to find it with `$("#mytable tr").has("input[type=hidden][value=HiddenFieldValue]").find("td:eq(0)")`.

Comment: It's working , thank you so much :)